# Why can extensions of a section of a vector bundle over a finite number of trivializing sets glue together?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

This is motivated by the proof of Theorem 6.8 in Bott and Tu's Differential forms in algebraic topology. In the second paragraph there, they make a claim which can be generalized as follows:

Suppose we have two topological spaces $Y$ and $I$. Suppose we have a section $s$ of some vector bundle $E \rightarrow Y \times I$ (which is the bundle of linear maps between two bundles in the book), **which is defined only over $Y \times \{ t_0 \}$**, with $t_0 \in I$ fixed. The claim is that, if $Y$ is compact, then $s$ can be extended to a neighborhood of $Y$ in $Y \times I$.

The argument is that we can find some open sets $U_1, \ldots, U_n$ in $Y \times I$ over which $E$ is trivial and such that $Y \times \{ t_0 \} \subset \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n U_i$. Obviously we can extend the section $s$ to sections $s_i$ over each $U_i$ using the trivializations. But how can we ensure that these $s_i$ glue together to a section on the whole $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n U_i$?

Comment: Assuming that we are working with topological manifolds, you could consider a continuous partition of unity $\{f_i\}$ subordinate to the covering $\{U_i\}$ of the submanifold $\mathcal{U}=\bigcup_{i=1}^nU_i\subset Y\times I$, and then define $\hat{s}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i f_i s_i$. The sum is well defined and $\hat{s}$ is a section of $E$, as each of the $f_i$ vanishes at the boundary of $U_i$. Moreover $\sum_if_i(t_0)=1$, so $\hat{s}(y,t_0)=s(y,t_0)$ for every $y\in Y$. I'm not really sure what would happen with general topological spaces.

Comment: @JohnnyLemmon But why would we need compacity of $Y$ then? Your argument seems to work well for a partition of unity subordinate to any cover...

Comment: Ah, but I don't see why you divide by $\frac{1}{n}$ at all!

Comment: I am sorry, you are right. That division does not make sense at all!

Comment: I went to read the Theorem in Bott-Tu that you are referring to. In their context $I=[0,1]$, and we have a section of the bundle defined on $Y\times\{t_0\}$ for some $t_0\in I$. If I understand correctly, they want to prove that this section can be extended to a section defined on $Y\times(t_0-\delta,t_0+\delta)$, for some $\delta>0$. As there is a finite number of trivializing $U_i$s, we can say that for some $\delta>0$, $Y\times(t_0-\delta,t_0+\delta)\subset\bigcup U_i$. If $Y$ wasn't compact, it might be instead that the $U_i$s necessary to cover $Y\times\{t_0\}$ get "infinitesimally thin".